# Baking Groove on mesh results in black color

Tags: texture-baking

I'm baking an object with groove on the surface, but after baking, the grooved part shows black, and I do not know why, my node step is as follow,

[image: Without using the baked texture]

[image: Using the baked texture, the grooved text is black]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this a stupid question, cause I engraved the text on the the sphere, I need to re unwrap the mesh, otherwise there will be uv coordinates and will results in black